# Xcode - No code highlight and tips in Objective-C and Swift mix project

Tags: xcode

I'm working on an Objective - C and Swift mixed project. and I found if I use objective-C class or call a method in Swift file , the Xcode did not show any code highlighted or any tips(auto completion）. is that normal? or I need set something?